# Differentiate between git repo and a directory of another repo

Tags: git

I have a git repo A and git repo B,
I've cloned repo A and inserted it to repo B as a directory.
so now I have this folder structure:

```
 B
 |-- some-other-folder
 |-- A-copy
```

Now I've continued developing repo B and also made some changes in folder A-copy.
I also made some minor changes in repo A.

- Is there a way I can see the differences between repo A and folder A-copy?
- Is there a way to take all changes done in repo B related to A-copy and commit them to repo A?

Comment: Putting a Git repository inside another Git repository is generally not a good idea unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: The short answer is yes, ill try to explain later on what needs to be done. Try to read about cherry-picking for now. you can add multiple origins to the same repo and then compare the content of them.

Comment: Time to read about submodules

Comment: @mkrieger1 the other repo was a dependency that the first repo used in code, and i prefered to have it locally, and develop it in the same repo and keep it under the same version, it's all working well.
I'll check the link that you sent.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you elaborate?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it seems like submodules is what I've needed in the first place, but I'm not sure how to check the diff and commit A-copy changes to A yet. im guessing i'll have to use both submodules and cherry-pick.
thank you for your assist I'll associate the post with the other post.

Comment: @Daniel. I was providing you with search terms, not an answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist i figured.. you could still elaborate more :). anyway thanks to mkrieger1 i managed to find a good direction to a solution using submodules.

Comment: @Daniel. Getting in the habit of researching for yourself is going to help you a lot more in the long term than the specific answer to this question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. ok i accept that. I was just in a rush to find a direction, and your comment was a bit blurry, and seemed a bit condescending at the time. I appreciate the direction to submodules.